# preventing combo box to assign an Item and filling its text

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, combobox, dataview

I'm trying below code to filter members of a combo box but unfortunately after typing first letter combo box automatically assigns first relevant member to the combo box and its text fills with display member of selected item. so user cannot continue typing other words to search among items.

```
    private void cmbCompany_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string QueryCompany = string.Format("select id,title from acc.dl union select null , null order by title");
        SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryCompany, con);
        con.Open();
        DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
        DA1.Fill(DT1);
        con.Close();
        DataView dv = new DataView(DT1);
        dv.RowFilter = "Title like '%" + cmbCompany.Text + "%'";
        cmbCompany.DisplayMember = "Title";
        cmbCompany.ValueMember = "id";
        cmbCompany.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

could you please provide any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

set these properties of combobox.

```
cmbCompany.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
cmbCompany.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Remove event `TextChanged`, and bind the `datasource` of the `combobox` once (in load or any other event).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string QueryCompany = string.Format("select id,title from acc.dl union select null , null order by title");
        SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryCompany, con);
        con.Open();
        DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
        DA1.Fill(DT1);
        con.Close();
        cmbCompany.DataSource = DT1;
        cmbCompany.DisplayMember = "Title";

    }
```

This should do what you expect.

Comment: i tried formload event but items don't update while typing new letters.

Comment: seems I misunderstand your question... you want to search from db directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
cmbCompany.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
cmbCompany.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```